# SQL one-to-many tables group by

Tags: sql, group-by, one-to-many

Let consider example: I have following tables - TableA with people and TableB containing language skills of these people. Each row describing person can have none, one or more rows in TableB. Example below:

```
People
+-----+--------+
| pId |  Name  |
+-----+--------+
|   0 | Thomas |
|   1 | Henry  |
|   2 | John   |
+-----+--------+

Skills
+-----+-----+----------+---------------+
| lID | pId | Language | LanguageSkill |
+-----+-----+----------+---------------+
|   0 |   0 | Dutch    |             0 |
|   1 |   0 | French   |             4 |
|   2 |   0 | Italian  |             2 |
|   3 |   2 | Italian  |             2 |
+-----+-----+----------+---------------+
```

Thomas knows dutch, french and italian, Henry doesn't know any foreign language and John knows italian.

What I want to get is the best known language for each person from TableA:

```
+--------+----------+
|  Name  | Language |
+--------+----------+
| Thomas | French   |
| Henry  | NULL     |
| John   | Italian  |
+--------+----------+
```

I have feeling that is quite easy thing, but don't have idea how to achieve it in a simple way.

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Will there ever be ties?  If so, what would you like to output?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the best language for each person using the following query:

```
SELECT pid, language
from TableB
group by pid
having languageskill = max(languageskill)
```

Then you join it onto the People table:

```
SELECT a.name, b.language
from TableA a
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT pid, language, languageskill
  from TableB
  group by pid
  having languageskill = max(languageskill)
) b
ON a.pid = b.pid
```

Of course, this method would not give more than one row if the person had a 'tied' best language, and you would lose that data about the 'tied' best language.

Comment: Sorry, you might need to add 'languageskill' to the select clause in the sub-select in some versions of SQL